# yii2 ActiveForm numeric textfield with decimal point

Tags: yii2, localization

In my form I need to get geo-positions as lat/lon:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'lat')->textInput(['type' => 'number']);
echo $form->field($model, 'lon')->textInput(['type' => 'number']);
```

in config/web.php the language is set to:

```
'language' => 'de',
```

The attribut rules in the Model are defind as:

```
[['lat'], 'number', 'min' => -90, 'max' => 90],
[['lon'], 'number', 'min' => -180, 'max' => 180],
```

When user inputs a 48.1234 the value is stored in the database. But when upating the model in the update form, there is a decimal comma shown. And there is a hint "incorrect format".

How do I preserve the decimal point coming from the database?

Comment: **there is a decimal comma shown** ? i dont get that, can you show an image of what is happening?

Comment: Yes, the update form gets filled with lat / lon values with decimal comma (48,1234). When the user submits this form, there is an error "invalid number" / "incorrect format". This is why I want to preserve the decimal point.

Comment: hmm... i remember 2 years back i had to work with the lat/long and i used the `geometry` type column to save the lat/long as `point(lat,long)` inside the `beforeSave()` and exploded them in `afterFind` to use them, and never ran into such problems. i can share if you like as it would be totaly different solution, but still i dont feel like any problem in the way you have done it should work correctly. is the value saved correctly? is there any `afterFind` in your model that is converting the decimals to , or any other js plugin? what is the data type of the column in database table?